# Cypress: any difference between cy.get("a").find("b") and cy.get("a b")

Tags: javascript, cypress

It seems like they're identical. Is there ever any difference in output between `cy.get("a").find("b")` and `cy.get("a b")`?

(Where `a` and `b` are some selectors, e.g. `div` and `span`, or `.someClass` and `.someOtherClass`.)

Comment: An interesting question. Technically, there will be two yields in the first case and just one in the second, but the matching pattern might work in a bit different way. Output should be the same, however.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no difference in result, but there is a difference in implementation.

From the docs for the `.find()` command:

> The querying behavior of this command matches exactly how `.find()` works in jQuery.

In other words,

```
cy.get("a").find("b");
```

is equivalent to the following JQuery:

```
$("a").find("b");
```

`$("a").find("b");` will produce the same result as `$("a b")`, but will use a different method to get there.

---

I've done a bit of testing to confirm this on a fairly complex page:

[image: testing result]

Notice how the number results is the same for `cy.get("td").find("tr")` and `cy.get("td tr")`.

Answer (score 37):

As you stated in your question there is not difference between `cy.get("a").find("b")` and `cy.get("a b")`. But the most important difference between `find` and `get` commands in Cypress is that [`cy.get()` is chained off of `cy`, it always looks for the selector within the entire `document` as stated in Cypress documents](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Get-in-within). But as again [stated in Cypress documents](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find.html#Syntax) find works as follows:

> Get the descendent DOM elements of a specific selector.

So the command `cy.get("a").find("b")` returns all the `b` elements which are successor of an `a` element, but `cy.get("a").get("b")` finds all the `a` and `b` elements regardless of they are parent and child.

Comment: Should your second example in the last paragraph be `cy.get("a").get("b")`?

Comment: Is there anything to know when it comes to performance? Is it better to use `cy.get("a b")` instead of `cy.get("a").find("b")`?

Comment: So I did a performance check for myself. I had a test that utilizes around 20 different selectors, all with nesting, and does some UI and IT checks.

It turned out that on average, running the test with each variants a few times, variant A (`cy.get("a b")`) is around 20-25 % faster than variant B (`cy.get("a").find("b")`).

That's why we chose to stick with variant A. I still find variant B more readable, so you decide what's better for you.

Comment: You are wrong stating that `cy.get()` is always looking for the selector inside the entire document. When you call `cy.get()` in combination with within it is scoped within this element. See: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#cyget-in-the-within-command

Comment: Minor clarification: "successor" and "descendant" seem different. I don't think "successor" is correct here--I think of that as a sibling at the same level of the node tree rather than a child or descendant inside the subtree.

Answer (score 3):

find() wont work on the cy rather it can work on a chained DOM.
the below command would throw error
cy.find('.progress')          // Errors, cannot be chained off 'cy'

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in the result, usually.

`cy.get("a").find("b").click()` will only retry `find('b').click()`, while `cy.get("a b").click()` will retry the whole selection `cy.get("a b")`.
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability#Only-the-last-command-is-retried

Usually both will get you the same result but when the result is different it is annoying to debug. I try and stick to one command as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using `cy.get("a").find("b")`.

Even though both yield the same result, this "two element" option is easier to mantain. It is faster identify which element is missing if the test breaks.